# Krull dimension of the quotient ring $k[x_1, ..., x_n]/(F)$.

Tags: commutative-algebra, krull-dimension

> Let $k$ be any field, and take any $0 \not = F \in k [x_1,..., x_n]$. Is it always the case that the Krull dimension of $k[x_1, ..., x_n]/(F)$ is $n-1$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by $k[x_1,..., x_n]$ you denoted a polynomial ring, then this is the case. In fact, $\dim k[x_1,..., x_n]/(F)=\sup\{\dim k[x_1,..., x_n]/P:P\text{ is a  minimal prime over }(F)\}$. Since $P$ minimal over $(F)$ its height is one, and then $\dim k[x_1,..., x_n]/P=n-1$.